# import images into magento

Tags: php, image, magento, import

I have several products and want to give them all the same image with the path:

```
/media/import/pic.jpg
```

This is just for a test. Later, I will add different images to each product so some parts of the code seem unnecessary.

That's what i came up with:

```
<?php
require_once('app/Mage.php'); 
umask(0);
Mage::app();
$importDir = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'import/';
$fileName = "pic.jpg";
$_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
               ->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
foreach($_productCollection as $_product)
{   
        $filePath = $importDir.$fileName;
        if ( file_exists($filePath) ) {
        try {
            $_product->addImageToMediaGallery($filePath, 'image', false);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
     }
}
?>
```

It does not work at all. What's wrong with it?

Comment: I solved it. You just need to add this part: $_product->save();

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the store id to admin

```
Mage::app('default');
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
```